# How to implement price range seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I need to the price range seekbar or slider like I have mentioned in the below image. Any help or sample code will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Price Range seek bar]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Comment: @FarhanShah Probably because you didn't show any effort, you just ask for code.

Comment: You are able to use style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete" in your SeekBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android has no such a view. But you can [create](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) custom components based on your need. For your particular case, [this one](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) should be fine. For more complex scenario, you can refer [this one](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar) on github.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i overview your links which u have suggested to me,but these links approach is so complex

Answer (score -3):

You can find a nice simple android seek bar example in the below links. Ofcourse, you can modify the same to cater to your custom needs later.

1. [JavaTechig](http://javatechig.com/android/android-seekbar-example/)
2. [ProgrammerGuru](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-seekbar-example/)
3. [CompileTimeError](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-seekbar-example.html)