# How to set progress in range seekbar in android

Tags: android

I have created a range seekbar like this https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/.Now my question is how to set progress in this.

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/83

Comment: not helpful.thanks for comment.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444470/how-to-implement-price-range-seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar/blob/master/rangeseekbar-sample/src/main/java/com/yahoo/mobile/client/android/demo/DemoActivity.java)

```
// Setup the new range seek bar
RangeSeekBar<Integer> rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(this);
// Set the range
rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(15, 90);
rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(20);
rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(88);
```

Comment: Thanx i have done like this.But this the answer of my question.